# How to get the data from a dynamically generated form in VUE?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, templates

**Hello Community**

I have a parent component that includes a child component, in which a form with different controls is dynamically rendered from a JSON object (obtained through a Get request from Axios).

**My objective** is to read / loop through all form fields values found in child component, from parent component. How would I do it with Vue JS?

Here is part of the code, if someone has proposals for improvements they will be well received. For example, better structure my code so that it is more organized and clean or use best programming practices with Vue. Thank you.

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <b-container>
      <b-card>
        <b-card-title>Formulario Dinámico</b-card-title>
        <b-card-body>
           <FormControls :fields="fields"></FormControls>
        </b-card-body>
        <b-card-footer>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="send">Enviar</button>
        </b-card-footer>
      </b-card>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FormControls from "./FormControls.vue";
import ComponentTest from "./ComponentTest.vue";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    FormControls,
    ComponentTest
  },
  created() { 
    axios.get('./src/form.json').then(response => this.fields = response.data); 
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Bienvenido',
      fields: [] // Array que almacenará el json proveniente de la petición get
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send: () => {
      alert('Enviar Formulario');
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**JSON**

```js
[
    {
      "name": "fechaRegistro",
      "label": "Fecha de Registro",
      "type": "date",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Fecha"
    },
    {
      "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
      "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario"
    },
    {
      "name": "passwordUsuario",
      "label": "Password",
      "type": "password",
      "placeholder": "Contraseña"
    },
    {
      "name": "adjuntarArchivo",
      "label": "Adjuntar",
      "type": "file"
    },
    {
      "name": "roles",
      "label": "Roles",
      "type": "select",
      "sortedByKey": false,
      "options": [{
          "name": "admin",
          "label": "Administrador"
        },
        {
          "name": "user",
          "label": "Usuario"
        },
        {
          "name": "guest",
          "label": "Invitado"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "label": "Descripción",
      "type": "textarea"
    },
    {
      "name": "multiSelect",
      "label": "Selección Multiple",
      "type": "multiselect",
      "options": [{
          "name": "op1",
          "label": "Opcion1"
        },
        {
          "name": "op2",
          "label": "Opcion2"
        },
        {
          "name": "op3",
          "label": "Opcion3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**Child Component**

```js
<template>
  <div>
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="field in fields" :key="field">
        <label :for="field.name">{{field.label}}</label>

        <input v-if="isInput(field.type)" 
        :id="field.name" :type="field.type" :placeholder="field.placeholder" >

        <select v-else-if="field.type === 'select'" :name="field.name">
          <option v-for="opt in field.options" :key="opt" :value="opt.name">
          {{opt.label}}
          </option>
        </select>

        <textarea v-else-if="field.type === 'textarea'" :id="field.name" />
        
        <div v-else-if="field.type === 'multiselect'" class="multi-select">
          <multiselect v-model="values" tag-placeholder="Agregar etiqueta" :placeholder="field.placeholder" label="label" track-by="name" :options="field.options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="agregarEtiqueta"></multiselect>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['fields'],
  name: 'FormControls',
  data () {
    return {
      titulo: 'Formulario Dinámico',
      // Aqui va lo del MultiSelect
      values: [],
      options: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isInput(type) {
      return ['text', 'password', 'checkbox', 'file', 'date'].includes(type);
    },
    // metodo multiselect
    agregarEtiqueta (newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        label: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.options.push(tag)
      this.value.push(tag)
    },
    devolverControl(){

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would probably make more sense for the child component to loop through its own fields.  It can emit up an object with whatever result it comes up with.

Comment: You can look at Vue Formulate library, it's pretty flexible and can generate forms from Json schema.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be meddling with children's data from the parent. That would be a tight coupling. Try the "dumb component" style, where your `input`s are only display components & accept props & emit data to the parent. This way you can validate the data in the parent, in any way you want.

A bit more complex solution would be to create the error-handlers inside your "dumb components", and only emit back "error" if they detect errors in themselves. Another style could be to create the validation functions in your `fields` dataset & just pass down the functions themselves (more of a **React** than a **Vue** approach - totally working & valid JS, just not really **Vue**-style).

In the snippet below I just added `value` & `error` to the field items, so they are fully present in the parent component.

```js
Vue.component("InputPassword", {
  props: ['field'],
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.field.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:value", {
          value
        })
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>{{ field.name }}: <input type="password" v-model="value" /></label>
      <span
        v-if="field.error"
      >
        THIS FIELD HAS ERRORS
      </span>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component("InputText", {
  props: ['field'],
  computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        return this.field.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:value", {
          value
        })
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <label>{{ field.name }}: <input type="text" v-model="value" /></label>
      <span
        v-if="field.error"
      >
        THIS FIELD HAS ERRORS
      </span>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [{
          "name": "nombreDeUsuario",
          "label": "Nombre de Usuario",
          "type": "text",
          "placeholder": "Ingresa Usuario",
          "value": null,
          "error": null,
        },
        {
          "name": "passwordUsuario",
          "label": "Password",
          "type": "password",
          "placeholder": "Contraseña",
          "value": null,
          "error": null,
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFormValid() {
      return this.fields.every(({
        error
      }) => error == false) ? "YES" : "NO"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleValidateForm() {
      this.fields = this.fields.map(field => {
        return {
          ...field,
          error: !(!!field.value) // valid if not empty
        }
      })
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <form>
        <component
          v-for="field in fields"
          v-bind:is="'input-' + field.type"
          v-bind="{
            field
          }"
          v-on="{
            'update:value': ({ value }) => {
              field.value = value
            },
          }"
        ></component>
      </form>
      <div
        v-for="(field, i) in fields"
        :key="'display-field-' + i"
      >
        field name: {{ field.name }}<br />
        field value: {{ field.value }}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <button
        @click="handleValidateForm"
      >
        VALIDATE
      </button>
      IS FORM VALID? {{ isFormValid }}
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```